# how nunique works with given table values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
yf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 1, 1]})
```

output:

```
A   B
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   1

yf.nunique(axis=0)
```

output:

```
A    3
B    1

yf.nunique(axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
```

could you please how `axis=0` and `axis=1` works? In `axis=0`, why `A=2, B=1` are ignored? Wonder if nunique gets in index as well?

Comment: `axis=1` means test by columns, `axis=0` test by rows

Comment: I know sir, but my question is: is not A=2, B=1 also unique as A=3 and B=1. Why A=2 and B=1 cannot be unique as well?

Comment: `A` is 3, because 3 unique values in column `A`, similar for `B`

Comment: but the output gives A=3 and B=1

Comment: `0` is `1`, because 1 number of uniqu values in row `0`

Comment: Oh, the nunique works with quantity amount (horiztanlly/vertically) but not by each value uniquness. thanks sir, I guess i got it now.

Comment: I thought A=3 and B=1 is from DataFrame values. Now, it is the quantity amount from DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test number of unique values per columns or per index by [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html).

```
yf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 1, 1]}) 
print (yf)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  1

print (yf.nunique(axis=0))
A    3
B    1
dtype: int64

print (yf.nunique(axis=1))
0    1
1    2
2    2
dtype: int64
```

It means:

```
A is 3, because 3 unique values in column A
0 is 1, because 1 unique values in row 0
```